# Forced Aligner doesn’t work on denoised sound file

Tags: phonology

I’m using p2fa to do aligning for a sound file. Because the speaker has some heavy breath that was misinterpreted as words, I used praat to denoise it, and it sounds pretty good. However, p2fa almost cannot detect any sound in the denoised file. Anyone knows one? Thanks!!